# javascript code not firing

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have a simple html & javascript code in my aspx file, but the javascript code is not firing. When I put a breakpoint, it isn't getting hit. Any ideas what I am missing here?

```
<input id="btnUpload" type="button" value="Save" onclick ="btnSave_Click()"/>



<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function btnSave_Click()
{
    if (!Page_ClientValidate('vgFormVals'))
        return false;

    document.getElementById('hfFilename').value = btnUpload_onclick(document.getElementById('SessionID').value);
    document.getElementById('btnSubmit').click();
}  

</script>
```

The code below is from ViewSource:

```
<input id="btnUpload" type="button" class="bigbutton" style="color:Black" value="Save" onclick ="btnSave_Click()"/>



    function btnSave_Click()
    {
        if (!Page_ClientValidate('vgFormVals'))
            return false;

        document.getElementById('hfFilename').value = btnUpload_onclick(document.getElementById('SessionID').value);
        document.getElementById('btnSubmit').click();
    }
```

**Update:** 
When I modify the code to add alerts as below, only the 1st alert is fired. None of the other 3 are fired.

```
function btnSave_Click() {
    alert("1");
    if (!Page_ClientValidate('vgFormVals'))
        alert("2");
    return false;

    alert("3");
    document.getElementById('hfFilename').value = btnUpload_onclick(document.getElementById('SessionID').value);
    document.getElementById('btnSubmit').click();
    alert("4"); }
```

Comment: Does the JavaScript console show any errors? Does the HTML look like that when it comes out of the ASP and into the browser?

Comment: Add the <script></script> tag

Comment: sorry... the <script> tags are existing. There is a bunch of javascript functions, I just posted the relevant code.

Comment: @Quentin not sure what you mean.

Comment: How are your .NET IDs rendered? Are you sure that the ID you type in your JavaScript `btnSubmit` etc, are the same as the ones actually rendered?

Comment: @user3929962 — You put an aspx file on the server. The server reads the file. The server passes the file through ASP.NET. ASP.NET modifies it, executing server side code and changing all sorts of things in the HTML. The server then sends the modified file back to the browser. Does the HTML still look like that when the browser gets it? Use *View > Source*.

Comment: @Quentin, yes, the code is the same in ViewSource

Comment: What you posted works fine by itself. You must have something else on the page breaking this somehow - either a javascript error or some other event handler stopping this one.

Answer (score 1):

Check for missing brackets in If-Statement: the function will currently always break after it because of the RETURN FALSE. Try it this way, with brackets:

```
function btnSave_Click() {
    alert("1");

    if (!Page_ClientValidate('vgFormVals')) {
       alert("2");
       return false;
    }

    alert("3");
    document.getElementById('hfFilename').value = btnUpload_onclick(document.getElementById('SessionID').value);
    document.getElementById('btnSubmit').click();
    alert("4"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the   runat="server"   statement in the input declaration?

```
<input id="btnUpload" type="button" value="Save" runat="server" onclick="btnSave_Click()"/>
```

Comment: Why ` runat="server" `? The code is talking about client validation?

Comment: 'cause we're talking about aspx, no?